# Clear previous files when uploading new files antd upload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I'm using antd `<Upload />` component so upload multiple files but the current behaviour is if the user uploads 2 files for the first time and again he uploads 1 more file again so the antd Upload onchange event return 3 files but I only want the file that has been uploaded recently, so any solution for it?

```
<Upload
    onChange={_.debounce(onUploadFiles, 100)}
    showUploadList={false}
    multiple
>
    <Button type="default" shape="round" className="main-upload-btn">
        <PlusOutlined /> Add Documents
    </Button>
</Upload>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by passing `fileList` prop as empty so it will always return newly uploaded files.

```
<Upload
    onChange={_.debounce(onUploadFiles, 100)}
    showUploadList={false}
    fileList={[]}
    multiple
>
    <Button type="default" shape="round" className="main-upload-btn">
        <PlusOutlined /> Add Documents
    </Button>
</Upload>
```